# Sinch mobile verification Skipping

Tags: android, verification, sinch

I have made an app in which first the user verifies its number with the help of sinch verification and then after succesfull verification it goes to the gameactivity  but the problem is that every time the user opens the app he or she has to verify again which is a very bad out come.

i dont how o skip the verification process after again opening the app

Main Activity

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String SMS = "sms";
    public static final String FLASHCALL = "flashcall";
    public static final String INTENT_PHONENUMBER = "phonenumber";
    public static final String INTENT_METHOD = "method";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        TextView phoneNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
        phoneNumber.setText(manager.getLine1Number());
    }

    private void openActivity(String phoneNumber, String method) {
        Intent verification = new Intent(this, VerificationActivity.class);
        verification.putExtra(INTENT_PHONENUMBER, phoneNumber);
        verification.putExtra(INTENT_METHOD, method);
        startActivity(verification);
    }

    private boolean checkInput() {
        TextView phoneNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
        if (phoneNumber.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please input a phone number.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void onButtonClicked(View view) {
        if (checkInput()) {
            TextView phoneNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
            if (view == findViewById(R.id.smsVerificationButton)) {
                openActivity(phoneNumber.getText().toString(), SMS);
            } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.callVerificationButton)) {
                openActivity(phoneNumber.getText().toString(), FLASHCALL);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Verification Activity

```
 public class VerificationActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = Verification.class.getSimpleName();
    private final String APPLICATION_KEY = "af23************************";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_verification);
        ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressIndicator);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent != null) {
            String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.INTENT_PHONENUMBER);
            String method = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.INTENT_METHOD);
            TextView phoneText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numberText);
            phoneText.setText(phoneNumber);
            createVerification(phoneNumber, method);
        }

    }

    void createVerification(String phoneNumber, String method) {
        Config config = SinchVerification.config().applicationKey(APPLICATION_KEY).context(getApplicationContext())
                .build();
        VerificationListener listener = new MyVerificationListener();
        Verification verification;
        if (method.equalsIgnoreCase(MainActivity.SMS)) {
            verification = SinchVerification.createSmsVerification(config, phoneNumber, listener);
        } else {
            TextView messageText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
            messageText.setText(R.string.flashcalling);
            verification = SinchVerification.createFlashCallVerification(config, phoneNumber, listener);
        }
        verification.initiate();
    }

    class MyVerificationListener implements VerificationListener {

        @Override
        public void onInitiated() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Initialized!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitiationFailed(Exception exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Verification initialization failed: " + exception.getMessage());
            hideProgress(R.string.failed, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerified() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Verified!");
            hideProgress(R.string.verified, true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(Exception exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Verification failed: " + exception.getMessage());
            hideProgress(R.string.failed, false);
        }
    }

    void hideProgress(int message, boolean success) {
        if (success) {
            ImageView checkMark = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.checkmarkImage);
            checkMark.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressIndicator);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        TextView progressText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progressText);
        progressText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        TextView messageText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        messageText.setText(message);
    }

}
```

I  just want that on re opening verification process should not be again called.

Comment: You can use `SharedPreferences` to locally manage if user is verified or not

Comment: I dont know how to use it ? any example ?

Comment: tutorials on shared preferences https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=shared%20preference%20example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SharedPreferences`. add a `key` to your SharedPreferences object and initialize with value `0`. You can do something like below

```
SharedPrefences prefences = PrefenceManager.getSharedPreferences("TAG",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
```

Now on successfull verification :

```
preferences.putInt("key",1);
```

so on next launch check for this `key` value, if its `1` skip the `VerificationActivity` and start `GameActivtiy` i.e

```
int value = preferences.getInt("key",0);

if(value == 0){
  // Verify
}else{
  // Skip Verification
}
```

Comment: Thanks just a second I am trying ok bro